# Correct object type in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to choose a type for holding object. But I need some help.

My object should have 3 property:

- small
- medium
- max

Each of them will hold URL

Also my object should have Preferred property. Which will be assigned as small, medium or max. And Preferred should return URL from selected property.

For example if I assign:

```
small = url1
medium = url2
max = url3
```

//Here also I have global settings class. And in that I should choose to return from preferred - max urls. And for every insnanse preferred should return max.

```
Class.preferred = Type.max //something like that
print(instanse.preferred) //printed url3
```

How can I archive that? I can not use Class here, but I am not sure can I archive that with enum?

Sample which does not work

```
enum VideoType: String {
case min
case med
case max
}


class VideoInstanse {
var min: VideoType
var med: VideoType
var max: VideoType

static var preferred:VideoType!

init(dictionary: [Int : String]) {
    min.rawValue = dictionary[1] //error
    med.rawValue = dictionary[2]
    max.rawValue = dictionary[3]
}
}
```

Comment: By creating a struct or class that does exactly that, where is your problem?

Comment: I added point about global settings, here is an issue

Comment: The last edit makes no sense. Why can't you use a class? What are you trying to do?

Comment: not sure what the actual issue is, but the line where it says `//error` won't compile because `[]` returns an optional. If you are certain that the dictionary contains valid values for `1, 2, 3`, you can simply write `min.rawValue = dictionary[1]!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in using an enum in this case (if I understand your question correctly)

```
enum Endpoint: String {
  var baseURLString: String {
    get {
      return "https://myurl.com?size=".appending(self.rawValue)
    }
  }

  case small
  case medium
  case max

  var url: URL? {
    return URL(string: baseURLString)
  }
}


print(Endpoint.small.url!)
print(Endpoint.medium.url!)
print(Endpoint.max.url!)
```

The output is:

```
https://myurl.com?size=small
https://myurl.com?size=medium
https://myurl.com?size=max
```

Comment: hi, I added enum sample, please check my question

Answer (score 0):

Struct, maybe?

```
struct Size {
    var small : NSURL = NSURL()
    var medium : NSURL = NSURL()
    var large : NSURL = NSURL()
}
class VideoInstanse {
    var properties = Size()


   func someMethod() {
    self.properties.small = url1
    self.properties.medium = url2
    self.properties.large = url3
   }
}
```

You can also use it Outside the class somewhere else like so:

```
var instance = VideoInstance()
instance.properties.small...
// and so on...
```